# I have a checkbox on which if I click a textfield unit configuration appears, i want to store that value

Tags: flutter

[image]

I have a checkbox on which if we click, a unit configuration TextField appeared and i want to store the value in it to send to the firestore. Below is my code, i have added the textEditingControllers but i can't able to use them, its showing error. How can i sort this out ?

I am unable to use the onChanged Value too, I think giving a single recurring TextField widget to the unit configurations is the problem, but how can i assign them to each checkbox ?

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCustomCheckbox extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomCheckbox(
      {super.key,
      required this.text,
      required this.value,
      required this.onChanged,
      this.padding = const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16)});

  final Text text;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;

  @override
  State<MyCustomCheckbox> createState() => _MyCustomCheckboxState();
}

class _MyCustomCheckboxState extends State<MyCustomCheckbox> {
  final TextEditingController oneBHK = TextEditingController();
  final twoBHK = TextEditingController();
  final threeBHK = TextEditingController();
  final fourBHK = TextEditingController();
  final fiveplusBHK = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        widget.onChanged(!widget.value);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: widget.padding,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: widget.text),
                Checkbox(
                  value: widget.value,
                  onChanged: (bool? newValue) {
                    widget.onChanged(newValue!);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            widget.value
                //.........................................
                //HERE IS THE TextFormField WIDGET
                //.........................................
                ? TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                    labelText: 'Enter Unit Configuration',
                  ))
                //SizedBox is just an empty placeholder
                : const SizedBox()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CheckBoxes extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckBoxes({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CheckBoxes> createState() => _CheckBoxesState();
}

class _CheckBoxesState extends State<CheckBoxes> {
  static List<String> selectedOptions = [];
  List<MyCustomCheckbox>? bhkOptions;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedOptions = [];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bhkOptions = [
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('1 BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('1 BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value!) {
              selectedOptions.add('1 BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('1 BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('2 BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('2 BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value!) {
              selectedOptions.add('2 BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('2 BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('3 BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('3 BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value!) {
              selectedOptions.add('3 BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('3 BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('4 BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('4 BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value!) {
              selectedOptions.add('4 BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('4 BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('5+ BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('5+ BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value!) {
              selectedOptions.add('5+ BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('5+ BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
    ];

    return Column(
      children: bhkOptions!,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to rewrite your code and made little changes to make it work for you:

- Pass `TextEditingController` as an argument to the `MyCustomCheckbox` widget.
- set the TextEditingController to Unit Configuration `TextFormField` so you can get the entered values and upload them to Firebase.
- Create all TextEditingController for each `BHK` option inside `_CheckBoxesState`
- `uploadToFirebase()` function that you can call to upload data to Firebase

Here is the modified code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCustomCheckbox extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomCheckbox({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.value,
    required this.onChanged,
    required this.unitConfiguration,
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
  });

  final Text text;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;
  final TextEditingController unitConfiguration;

  @override
  State<MyCustomCheckbox> createState() => _MyCustomCheckboxState();
}

class _MyCustomCheckboxState extends State<MyCustomCheckbox> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        widget.onChanged(!widget.value);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: widget.padding,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: widget.text),
                Checkbox(
                  value: widget.value,
                  onChanged: (bool? newValue) {
                    widget.onChanged(newValue!);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            widget.value
                ? TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                      labelText: 'Enter Unit Configuration',
                    ),
                    controller: widget.unitConfiguration,
                  )
                //SizedBox is just an empty placeholder
                : const SizedBox()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CheckBoxes extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckBoxes({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CheckBoxes> createState() => _CheckBoxesState();
}

class _CheckBoxesState extends State<CheckBoxes> {
  static List<String> selectedOptions = [];
  List<MyCustomCheckbox>? bhkOptions;

  //TextEditingControllers for all bhkOptions
  final oneBHK = TextEditingController();
  final twoBHK = TextEditingController();
  final threeBHK = TextEditingController();
  final fourBHK = TextEditingController();
  final fivePlusBHK = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedOptions = [];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bhkOptions = [
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('1 BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('1 BHK'),
        unitConfiguration: oneBHK,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value) {
              selectedOptions.add('1 BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('1 BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('2 BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('2 BHK'),
        unitConfiguration: twoBHK,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value) {
              selectedOptions.add('2 BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('2 BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('3 BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('3 BHK'),
        unitConfiguration: threeBHK,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value) {
              selectedOptions.add('3 BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('3 BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('4 BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('4 BHK'),
        unitConfiguration: fourBHK,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value) {
              selectedOptions.add('4 BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('4 BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('5+ BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('5+ BHK'),
        unitConfiguration: fivePlusBHK,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value) {
              selectedOptions.add('5+ BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('5+ BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
    ];

    return Column(
      children: bhkOptions!,
    );
  }
  
  void gotoSecondPage() async {
    final unitConfigurations = UnitConfiguration(
      oneBhk: oneBHK.text,
      twoBhk: twoBHK.text,
      threeBhk: threeBHK.text,
      fourBhk: fourBHK.text,
      fivePlusBhk: fivePlusBHK.text,
    );
    //navigate to next page
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => SecondScreen(unitConfiguration: unitConfigurations),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Create a new model class to hold all these values

```
class UnitConfiguration {
  final String? oneBhk;
  final String? twoBhk;
  final String? threeBhk;
  final String? fourBhk;
  final String? fivePlusBhk;

  UnitConfiguration({this.oneBhk, this.twoBhk, this.threeBhk, this.fourBhk, this.fivePlusBhk});
}
```

Assume below is the second screen where you want to set these values

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // Requiring the list of todos.
  const SecondScreen({super.key, required this.unitConfiguration});

  final UnitConfiguration unitConfiguration;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
  
}
```

Comment: I don't want to update to firebase in this page i want to update these values in another page.

Comment: Hi @hemanth_101 I have updated my answer, please check. You can wrap the values into the **UnitConfiguration** model and pass it to other page where you want to update

Comment: Tq for helping me out I will surely check and update !!

Comment: In stateful widget where should i place the required this.unitConfiguration.

Comment: class BuilderAddProperty extends StatefulWidget {
  const BuilderAddProperty({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BuilderAddProperty> createState() => _BuilderAddPropertyState();
}

Comment: I am getting into lot of errors like unitconfiguration declaration errors, I have also changed the required code.

Comment: in your case, you should declare the  unitConfiguration property in your BuilderAddProperty class:

class BuilderAddProperty extends StatefulWidget { 
final UnitConfiguration unitConfiguration;
const BuilderAddProperty({Key? key, required this.unitConfiguration}) : super(key: key); @override State<BuilderAddProperty> createState() => _BuilderAddPropertyState(); }